# Installing XtraBackup on Centos 6

Tags: mysql, centos6, rpm, percona, xtrabackup

I’m trying to install XtraBackup on centos 6 using [this](https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/installation/yum_repo.html) guid but i get these errors:

```
Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (C6.10-base)
Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (C6.10-base)
Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
```

I searched for the file but i have libmysqlclient.so.18 instead of libmysqlclient.so.16

My mysql version is 5.6

And i’ve already installed libev

please help

Comment: And the link to the guide is?

Comment: @RomeoNinov The hyperlink edited

Comment: For CentOS 6 all the products are not available (and the version is out of support long time a go), migrate to RHEL 8 and then install.